# Return nested custom object from JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have big problem. Spring Boot JPA does not like me. I have simple requirements

Return List of object which contains object from query.

Objects:

```
public class Foo {
    String a;
    Bar bar;
    public Foo(String a, final Bar bar) {
        this.a = a;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    int b;
    Bar(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Now I have query in repository:

```
@Query("select new bla.blub.Foo(query.a, new bla.blub.Bar(query.b))")
    List<Foo> lol();
```

But Spring Boot seems like stuped because I cannot nest the new calls to my object when another object needs this object in the constructor.

What to do? Me try specifications and query and out of answer.
thank you humans

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have your Foo accept query.b (int) directly and have it call new bla.blub.Bar(query.b)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could be using:

```
public class Foo {
    String a;
    Bar bar;
    public Foo(String a, int b) {
        this(a, new Bar(b));
    }
    public Foo(String a, final Bar bar) {
        this.a = a;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

and then for the query:

```
@Query("select new bla.blub.Foo(entity.a,entity.b) from Entity entity")
```